# How to compile multiple csv files while checking for duplicate row titles and co-adding new data

Tags: python, csv

I have searched quite thoroughly attempting to find an answer to my question with no luck.

To explain my question slightly better, I am tasked with merging multiple .csv files while also doing some other stuff. For example, lets say I have three files called run_1.csv, run_2.csv and run_3.csv which are all located in a single directory called /runs/

run_1.csv looks like:

```
Name, Mass (kg), run_1
One, 1, 5.4
Two, 2, 4.5
Three, 3, 6.5
```

run_2.csv looks like:

```
Name, Mass (kg), run_2
One, 1, 5.7
Two, 2, 6.7
```

and run_3.csv looks like:

```
Name, Mass (kg), run_3
One, 1, 4.7
Three, 3, 5.9
Four, 4, 2.0
```

I want my output file (output.csv) to look like this: (Note, the order of the rows does not matter)

```
Name, Mass (kg), run_1, run_2, run_3
One, 1, 5.4, 5.7, 4.7
Two, 2, 4.5, 6.7, 
Three, 3, 6.5, , 5.9 
Four, 4, , , 2.0
```

Currently, I am working in the csv module and have done something like this:

```
import os
import csv

fields = ['name', 'mass', 'run_1', 'run_2', 'run_3']

with open('output.csv', 'wb') as csvfile :
writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=",")
writer.writerow(fields) #write the header

file_names= []
for file in os.listdir(/runs/):
    file_names.append(file)

    with open(/runs/+file_name+'.csv', 'rb') as infile:
        reader = csv.reader(infile)
        reader.next() #just skipping the first row, the header

        entries = set()
        for row in reader:
            line = []
            key = row[0]
            time = row[2]

            if key not in entries:
                row.remove(row[-1])
                line.extend(row)
                for number in images_full:
                    line.append('')

                line.insert(fields.index(file_name.strip('.csv')), time)

                writer.writerow(line)

            elif key in entries:
                row.remove(row[-1])
                line.extend(row)
                for number in images_full:
                    line.append('')

                line.insert(fields.index(file_name.strip('.csv')), time)

                writer.writerow(line) #BUT, I only want it too add this data into the missing spot, not overwrite the whole line!
```

So I am at a loss and would greatly appreciate any help. The input csv files are able to be changed, however I believe there is a way to accomplish this the way that they are.

**EDIT: This was solved by reading in the original csv's into a dictionary, then writing them out after, see below:**

```
counter = 0
with open(/result+total_data_file_name, 'wb') as outfile:
writer = csv.writer(outfile)
writer.writerow(fields)
fields.pop(0)

for names in result.keys():
    line = []
    name = result.keys()[counter]
    line.append(name)

    for field_key in fields:
        try:
            line.append(result[name][field_key])

        except KeyError:
            line.append('')
    counter += 1

    writer.writerow(line)
```

Answer (score 1):

This will put all the values below the headers into a dict removing dups, you can just write your headers and then write the key/values.

```
from collections import defaultdict
new_data_dict = {}

files = ["in.csv","in2.csv","in3.csv"]
for f in files:
    with open(f) as f:
        f.next()
        for row in f:
            row = row.strip().split(",")
            new_data_dict.setdefault(row[0],set())
            new_data_dict[row[0]].update(row[1:])

{'Four': set([' 2.0', ' 4']), 'Three': set([' 3', ' 6.5', ' 5.9']), 'Two': set([' 2', ' 6.7', ' 4.5']), 'One': set([' 5.7', ' 5.4', ' 1', ' 4.7'])}
```

To write the data:

```
import csv
new_data_dict = {}
files = ["in.csv","in2.csv","in3.csv"]
headers = set()
for f in files:
    with open(f) as f:
        headers.update(f.next().rstrip().split(",")[2:])
        for row in f:
            row = row.strip().split(",")
            new_data_dict.setdefault(row[0],set())
            new_data_dict[row[0]].update(row[1:])
headers = ["Name","Mass (kg)"] + sorted(headers,key=lambda x: int(x.split("_")[-1]))

with open("out.csv","w") as out:
    writer = csv.writer(out)
    writer.writerow(headers)
    for k,v in new_data_dict.items():
        writer.writerow([k]+list(v))
```

To preserve order:

```
for f in files:
    with open(f) as f:
        headers.update(f.next().rstrip().split(",")[2:])
        for row in f:
            row = row.strip().split(",")
            new_data_dict.setdefault(row[0],[])
            new_data_dict[row[0]]+= row[1:]
headers = ["Name","Mass (kg)"] + sorted(headers,key=lambda x: int(x.split("_")[-1]))

with open("out.csv","w") as out:
    writer = csv.writer(out)
    writer.writerow(headers)
    for k,v in new_data_dict.items():
        writer.writerow([k]+sorted(set(v),key=lambda  x: new_data_dict[k].index(x)))

Name,Mass (kg), run_1, run_2, run_3
Four, 4, 2.0
Three, 3, 6.5, 5.9
Two, 2, 4.5, 6.7
One, 1, 5.4, 5.7, 4.7
```

Comment: it looks like using dictionaries is going to be a key in this, I will definitely work on my code to integrate them. However, your code does not preserve the columns. For example, the Mass of Name 'Four' is not 2.0, rather it is 4, which is in the next column. I could be looking at that the wrong way...

Comment: I your output you have `One, 1, 5.4, 5.7, 4.7` which is which in that?

Answer (score 0):

I think a dictionary is what you want for storing the key/value pairs.  Also, you'll want to parse all the files first before writing anything out.

**Edit: a dictionary of dictionaries will work if you need blanks for runs where there wasn't an entry for a certain field.**

```
import os
import csv
import string

fields = ['name', 'mass', 'run_1', 'run_2', 'run_3']

with open('output.csv', 'wb') as csvfile :
   writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=",")
   writer.writerow(fields) #write the header

   file_names= []

   # Use a dictionary to store result of all runs.
   # Each key is this dictionary is a string like 'One', 'Two', 'Three', etc.
   # The values are themselves dictionaries, with a key of the run index.
   runs = dict()

   # parse all the files first
   for file in os.listdir('runs/'):
      file_names.append(file)

      with open('runs/'+file, 'rb') as infile:
         reader = csv.reader(infile)
         reader.next() #just skipping the first row, the header

         # Get the run index for the sub-key
         temp = string.rstrip(file,'.csv')
         run_index = int(string.lstrip(temp,'runs_'))

         for row in reader:            
            key = row[0]
            index = row[1]
            time = row[2]

            # make the key a string like "Four 4"
            key = key + ' ' + index # use whitespace delimeter

            if key not in runs: 
               # create a new dict entry
               runs[key] = dict()
               runs[key][run_index] = time
            elif key in runs:   
               # add to the existing dict
               value = runs[key]                             
               value[run_index] = time
               runs[key] = value                           

   # find the run with max number of elements in its sub-dictionary
   max_entries = 0
   key_w_max_entries = -1
   for key in runs.keys():
      if len(runs[key].keys()) > max_entries:
         max_entries = len(runs[key].keys())
         key_w_max_entries = key

   # now write out the dictionary values             
   for key in runs.keys():
      line = []
      words = key.split() # split on whitespace
      for word in words:
         line.append(word)
      for i in runs[key_w_max_entries].keys():
         try:
            line.append(str(runs[key][i]))
         except:
            # if the key doesn't exist in the sub-dictionary, fill in a blank
            line.append(' ')
      writer.writerow(line)
```

Gives me a file like this:

```
name,mass,run_1,run_2,run_3
One,1, 5.4, 5.7, 4.7
Three,3, 6.5, , 5.9
Two,2, 4.5, 6.7, 
Four,4, , , 2.0
```

Comment: I like the simplicity of what you have done, but similarly to Padraic's suggestion, the output code does not contain the blank information in columns where the is no information. Ie, name Four has no given information for run_1, however your output file has that run_1 was 2.0 seconds. However, I might see a solution with the way that you write last, give me a few hours and I will comment back.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that you wanted blanks in your output file.  

Do the blanks need to correspond to particular runs?  

Or does it just matter that there are equal blanks/entries to the number of runs? i.e. for run 'Four', could I add ", , " at the end?

Comment: Thanks for responding back, yes the blanks need to correspond to whatever run it was.  I am an astrophysicist and am using the code to compile data on exoplanet detections. Each exoplanet has information for some of the images (which correspond to a single csv) and for other csv's they might not be on the frame so that should be represented with a blank.

Comment: See my latest edit.  You'll probably want to make 'fields' populated dynamically to support different numbers of runs.